# Retrieving data from push() in firebase kotlin that equal to the selected value

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Hello can someone that can help me to retrieve the data of selected value from generate key or push in Realtime Database Firebase. Nothings happen when I clicking the button I think my child is not order correctly. This is the collection tree from firebase;

[image]

```
val btnSyncing = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.btnSync)
    btnSyncing.setOnClickListener {
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val userid = user!!.uid
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        reference = database.getReference("Profile")
        val timeTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtTime)
        val dateTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtDate)
        reference.child(userid)
            .child("Delivery Details").orderByChild("Date").equalTo("24/9/22")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    val time = dataSnapshot.child("Time").value as String?
                    val date = dataSnapshot.child("Details").value as String?

                    timeTextView.text = time
                    dateTextView.text = date
                }
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Something wrong happened!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            })}
```

Comment: Is any of the `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` even triggered? What is the location of your database?

Comment: onDataChange, and my location is on firebase if i click the button not working the restoring data. I think the issue is on my reference, how can i do?

Comment: Please answer my first comment.